# upload image to server and then it fetch in android

Tags: php, android

i have **USERS** table in phpmyadmin data base. in the table i have a column which holds link to the user profile picture. but i think the image i`m uploading its not good. when i open it i see just a little square like this:

[image]

**EDIT: the picture part is fixed**

and when i`m trying to fetch it with piccaso i get nothing.
the way i upload the picture is encoding it to string and then decode it in the register.php

**this is the method which converting to image to string:**

```
 public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }
```

**this is my php where im uploading the image:**

```
$firstName = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastname'];
$passWord = $_POST['password'];
$phoneNumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
$apartmentNumber = $_POST['apartmentNumber'];
$image = $_POST['image']; //this is the encoded string

//upload image to image folder in the server    
$upload_folder = "upload";
$path = "$upload_folder/$phoneNumber.jpeg";
if(file_put_contents($path, base64_encode($image)) != flase){
    echo "uploaded";
}
$image_link = "my url/$path";
$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Users (firstName, lastname, password, phone , apartmentNum,image) 
        VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$EncryptPassword', '$phoneNumber', '$apartmentNumber' ,'$image_link')");
```

**this is the php where i`m creating the json object:**

```
$sql = ("select * from Users where phone = '$phone' and password = '$password' ");

$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

if(isset($check)){
    $hasApartment = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($hasApartment);
    $apartmentNumber = $row['apartmentNum'];
        $firstName = $row['firstName'];
        $lastName = $row['lastname'];
        $image = $row['image'];
 echo '{"query_result":"SUCCESS", "apartmentNumber":' . $apartmentNumber.' , "firstName":' . trim($firstName) .' ,"lastName":' . trim($lastName).', "image":' . $image.'}';

        }
```

**i get this exception:**

```
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 102 of {"query_result":"SUCCESS", "apartmentNumber":54 , "firstName":a ,"lastName":a, "image":XXXXXX.XX.XX/upload/112.jpeg}
```

**this is the json object:**

{"query_result":"SUCCESS", "apartmentNumber":54 , "firstName":a ,"lastName":a, "image":XXXXXX.XX.XX/upload/112.jpeg}

char 102 its the "u" in upload

**This is whers i do a GET request. In onResponse() i try to handle the json text as json object:**

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {

                            String query_result = response.getString("query_result");
                            switch (query_result){
                                case "SUCCESS": // user name and password exists and mathces and user associated with apartment
                                    int apartmentNum = Integer.parseInt(response.get("apartmentNumber").toString());

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivityScreen.this , HomeActivityScreen.class);

                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

                                    editor.putString("phoneNumber" , PhoneValidationActivity.PHONE_NUMBER);
                                    editor.putString("firstName", response.getString("firstName"));
                                    editor.putString("lastName", response.getString("firstName"));
                                    editor.putBoolean("loggedIn", true);
                                    editor.putInt("apartmentNumber", apartmentNum);

                                    Bitmap profilePicture = Picasso.with(context).load("http://roomates.96.lt/upload/0547517307.jpeg").get();

                                    editor.apply();

                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    break;

                                case "FAILURE":  //user name or password are incorrect
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong name or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) { //this exception is caught 
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("e" , e.toString());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("e", e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRquestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

Comment: `this is my php where im uploading the image:`. No. That is a php script that receives the image and then does something with it.

Comment: `am i uploading it ok?`. How should we know? There is no uploading code.

Comment: When are you getting that exception? With which statement? And why didnt you tell which is character 102?

Comment: `(file_put_contents($path, base64_encode($image)) ` ??? It is base64 ENCODED so you should DECODE it.

Comment: @greenapps you right its should be base64_decode, changed it. and iv`e gave the upload php script. all im doing in java its encoding the Bitmap in the getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) method and then post the encoded string to the server

Comment: @greenapps the char at 102 its the "u" in upload. i edited the question

Comment: Its difficult to follow you. `i  get this exception:`. Do you mean: Picasso throws that exception? If you first had said that you used picasso to download and then tell an exception you would be better to follow.

Comment: So Picasso is downloading a base64 encoded image. Can Picaso handle base64?

Comment: Do you see the diference between `"query_result":"SUCCESS"` and `"image":XXXXXX.XX.XX/upload/112.jpeg`? Syntactically?

Comment: i`m sorry for not being clear. my problem right now its only with the json object. its catching my the json.JSONException: Unterminated object exception before i can do anything. it doesnt get to the Bitmap profilePicture = Picasso.with(context).load("my image url").get(); command. i edited the question once again

Comment: Then why are you posting all that code in onResponse()? `this is where im trying to get the json objcet:`. Unclear and confusing. Better: This is whers i do a GET request. In onResponse() i try to handle the json text as json object.

Comment: Now tell which statement causes that exception. You can find it in the LogCat. Post the relevant lines. And why dont you react on my syntax question?

Comment: Remove  the `switch(query_succes)`  from onResponse.. You will still have the exception.

Comment: @greenapps i know the exception is caught in onRespone() because the json object its not good. i also see the difference in the syntax but i dont know how to add the quotes.

Comment: @greenapps nvm solved it

Comment: You are supposed to tell what the problem exactly was and how you solved it. And what is nvm?

Comment: the problem was the quotes in the json object. i solved it by adding them like this:  "image":"' . $image.'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String query_result = response.getString("query_result")
```

Do you see the diference between `"query_result":"SUCCESS"` and `"image":XXXXXX.XX.XX/upload/112.jpeg` ?

Syntactically?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting error in JSON response on image path then you should simply **json_encode** your response that way your all the special characters will be escaped properly.

In you JSON response your image path **XXXXXX.XX.XX/upload/112.jpeg** should be escaped like this **XXXXXX.XX.XX/upload/112.jpeg**.

Hope it helps you.